# Puppeteer page.goto error only with readFileSync

Tags: url, puppeteer, readfile

When using await page.goto('http://www.URL.edu') a PDF is generated, but when loading the same URL from a csv file, Puppeteer returns error.

Thought is might have been either a timing issue or a redirect from http to https, but the script proves both not to be the problem.

The commented out is where the url is loaded from a single CSV file with one row: "1,oldwestbury.edu,SUNY College at Old Westbury"

```
var dir1 = './screenshots';
var dir2 = './pdfs';
const fs = require('fs');

if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
}

if (!fs.existsSync(dir2)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir2);
}

function readURLFile(path) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
        .split('\n')
        .map((elt) => {
            const url = elt.split(',')[1].replace('\r', '');
            return `http://${url.toLowerCase()}`;
        });
}

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const startDate = new Date().getTime();
    const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36';
    const urls = readURLFile('./UNVurls.csv');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    for (let url of urls) {
        console.log(`Visiting url: ${url}`);
        let page = await browser.newPage();

        try {
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 900, deviceScaleFactor: 2 });

            await page.goto('http://www.oldwestbury.edu')

            // await page.goto(url, {
                // waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
                // timeout: 0
            // });


            let fileName = url.replace(/(\.|\/|:|%|#)/g, "_");
            if (fileName.length > 100) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, 100);
            }

            await page.waitForSelector('title');
            await page.screenshot({
                path: `./screenshots/${fileName}.jpeg`,
                omitBackground: true
            });

            await page.emulateMedia('screen');

            await page.pdf({
                path: `./pdfs/${fileName}.pdf`,
                pageRanges: "1",
                format: 'A4',
                printBackground: true
            });

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`An error occured on url: ${url}`);
        } finally {
            await page.close();
        }
    }

    await browser.close();
    console.log(`Time elapsed ${Math.round((new Date().getTime() - startDate) / 1000)} s`);

})();
```

Hoping to determine WHY the PDF is created when using the url direct and why the page load fails when retrieving from CSV file.

Comment: Reviewed "I am facing similar kind of issue with puppeteer@1.12.2 where its not able to detect the URL moved from HTTP to HTTPS." at [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3941) but does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: You have a try/catch block, but you don't actually make use of `err` recieved, what does it say? Also, does the target site actually work? I tried to open it from NY and had *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET* error.

Comment: The target site is http://www.oldwestbury.edu
https://imgur.com/9SPiJ8f

Comment: And what about errors, are there any in catch block?

Comment: That is the challenge... what the error is?  The catch block is returning the hard coded text when an error occurs.

Comment: Maybe you could change the code in it... log the `err`, for example, the one that is passed into catch block.